# How can I hook into the standard events offered by Global.asax in an Orchard CMS module?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I have the need to handle certain events from within an Orchard module. In a plain MVC app, I could just use Global.asax and handle events such as `Application_Error` and `Session_End` from there.

However, I need to now do this from with a module.

Are there any implementations of `IEventHandler` that allow me to hook into these events? Or can anyone suggest another way for me to achieve this?

Comment: You need to be more specific and tell us what exactly you are trying to do, otherwise, you'll only get answers such as "yes, there are events that you can use", which won't be very useful.

Comment: I need to know when a user's session ends, and I would also like to implement my own error handling.

Answer (score 0):

According with this discussion, it's not possible at the moment:
http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/278388